# Filtering data in JSON for any date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datepicker

I have a json file in the following format:

```
    [
  {
    "date_hour": "2014-04-30T18:30:00Z",
    "metric": 6986,
    "metric_ly": 4337,
    "mv": "OTHERS",
    "time_period": "Daily",
    "platform": "MWEB",
    "visits": 8624,
    "pv_visits": 6879,
    "atc_visits": 335,
    "ic_visits": 0,
    "orders": 72
  },
  {
    "date_hour": "2014-04-30T18:30:00Z",
    "metric": 5556372,
    "metric_ly": 3843986,
    "mv": "SEO",
    "time_period": "Daily",
    "platform": "CORESITE",
    "visits": 2005259,
    "pv_visits": 1043922,
    "atc_visits": 130590,
    "ic_visits": 64320,
    "orders": 53760
  }
  ]
```

I need a date slider or selecor(or any GUI,one that preferably is built using javascript) using which the data of this JSON file can be filtered for a given range of dates. Any suggestions as to which library should I use?

Comment: [You could use any](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=date+slider+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=h56NU5ulN8nVjwfHxIFg). You'd just have to map the JSON first.

Comment: How can that be done? Can you post any link to a tutorial that tells the same?

Comment: It seems you need to read more about JavaScript and try more basic programs before you jump into something like this. Ultimately, to map the JSON, you'd want to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map or http://api.jquery.com/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a silder widget to your liking (there are dozens out there), and assuming your slider widget provides two date values (startDate and endDate), I would use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) for something like this:

```
var filteredDates = _.filter(values, function(value){ 
    return (value.date_hour.getTime() > startDate.getTime() &&  
        value.date_hour.getTime() < endDate.getTime())
});
```