# How to insert a date slider in leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, leaflet

I am building a map for my project.to make work easier and quick decisions. I loaded JSON file from local and I pointed those markers in the map with filter conditions and different icons. Now I need to add a date slicer based on properties in the JSON. so my map looks like this:
[image]

now I need to add a date range which need to filter based n properties only true values show rest should remove from map.Am new for javascript s I developed my code based on given examples in google.below is my code

```js
var mapboxTiles =L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});
var greendelivery = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/green.png',
  iconRetinaUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-icon-2x.png',
  iconSize:    [25, 41],
  iconAnchor:  [12, 41],
  popupAnchor: [1, -34],
  shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
  shadowSize:  [41, 41]
});
var pickupblue = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/blue.png',
  iconRetinaUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-icon-2x.png',
  iconSize:    [25, 41],
  iconAnchor:  [12, 41],
  popupAnchor: [1, -34],
  shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
  shadowSize:  [41, 41]
});
var edapyellow = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/yellow.png',
  iconRetinaUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-icon-2x.png',
  iconSize:    [25, 41],
  iconAnchor:  [12, 41],
  popupAnchor: [1, -34],
  shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
  shadowSize:  [41, 41]
});
var flexred = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/red.png',
  iconRetinaUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-icon-2x.png',
  iconSize:    [25, 41],
  iconAnchor:  [12, 41],
  popupAnchor: [1, -34],
  shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
  shadowSize:  [41, 41]
});
var map = L.map('map')
 .addLayer(mapboxTiles)
 .setView([39.59, -105.32], 14);
 var promise = $.getJSON("testfinal.json");
 promise.then(function(data) {
   console.log(data)

  var alldata = L.geoJson(data);
  var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
          position: "topright",
          layer: alldata, 
          range: false,
});
  map.addControl(sliderControl);
      //And initialize the slider
sliderControl.startSlider();

       var delivery = L.geoJson(data, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
      return feature.properties.Type == "DELIVERY";
    },
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      return L.marker(latlng, {
        icon: greendelivery
      }).on('mouseover', function() {
        this.bindPopup("Name: " + feature.properties.Customer + "<br>" + "Address: " + feature.properties.fulladdress+ "<br>" + "Date: " + feature.properties.Date+ "<br>" + "Scheduled Time: " + feature.properties.Scheduled_Time+ "<br>" + "Qty Pieces: " + feature.properties.Qty_Pieces+ "<br>" + "Route: " + feature.properties.Route+ "<br>" + "Order_Id " + feature.properties.Sale_Order).openPopup();
      });
    }
  });
  var pickup = L.geoJson(data, {
      filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.Type == "PICKUP";
      },
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
          icon: pickupblue
        }).on('mouseover', function() {
          this.bindPopup("Name: " + feature.properties.Customer + "<br>" + "Address: " + feature.properties.fulladdress+ "<br>" + "Date: " + feature.properties.Date+ "<br>" + "Scheduled Time: " + feature.properties.Scheduled_Time+ "<br>" + "Qty Pieces: " + feature.properties.Qty_Pieces+ "<br>" + "Route: " + feature.properties.Route+ "<br>" + "Order_Id " + feature.properties.Sale_Order).openPopup();
        });
      }
  });
  var edap = L.geoJson(data, {
      filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.Type == "EXOP DELIVERY AND PICKUP";
      },
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
          icon: edapyellow
        }).on('mouseover', function() {
          this.bindPopup("Name: " + feature.properties.Customer + "<br>" + "Address: " + feature.properties.fulladdress+ "<br>" + "Date: " + feature.properties.Date+ "<br>" + "Scheduled Time: " + feature.properties.Scheduled_Time+ "<br>" + "Qty Pieces: " + feature.properties.Qty_Pieces+ "<br>" + "Route: " + feature.properties.Route+ "<br>" + "Order_Id " + feature.properties.Sale_Order).openPopup();
        });
      }
  }); 
  var flex = L.geoJson(data, {
      filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.Type == "flexischeduling";
      },
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
          icon: flexred
        }).on('mouseover', function() {
          this.bindPopup("Name: " + feature.properties.Customer + "<br>" + "Address: " + feature.properties.fulladdress+ "<br>" + "Date: " + feature.properties.Date+ "<br>" + "Scheduled Time: " + feature.properties.Scheduled_Time+ "<br>" + "Qty Pieces: " + feature.properties.Qty_Pieces+ "<br>" + "Route: " + feature.properties.Route+ "<br>" + "Order_Id " + feature.properties.Sale_Order).openPopup();
        });
      }
  }); 
  var sftruck3=L.geoJson(data, {
      filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.Route == "sftruck3";
      },
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng,{color:'#ff3333'}, {radius: 1500}).addTo(map);
      }
  });

  var sftruck1=L.geoJson(data, {
      filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.Route == "sftruck1";
      },
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng,{color:'#cfff33'}, {radius: 1500}).addTo(map);
      }
  });


  map.fitBounds(alldata.getBounds(), {
    padding: [60, 60]
  });
  delivery.addTo(map)   
  pickup.addTo(map)
  edap.addTo(map)
  flex.addTo(map)
  map.removeLayer(sftruck1)
  map.removeLayer(sftruck3)

  var baseLayers = {
  sftruck1: sftruck1,
  sftruck3: sftruck3
};
L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);

alllayer=L.layerGroup([delivery, pickup, edap, flex]).addTo(map)



  $("#DELIVERY").click(function() {
    map.addLayer(delivery)
    map.removeLayer(pickup)
    map.removeLayer(edap)
    map.removeLayer(flex)
  });
  $("#PICKUP").click(function() {
    map.addLayer(pickup)
    map.removeLayer(delivery)
    map.removeLayer(edap)
    map.removeLayer(flex)
  });
  $("#EXOP DELIVERY AND PICKUP").click(function() {
    map.addLayer(edap)
    map.removeLayer(delivery)
    map.removeLayer(pickup)
    map.removeLayer(flex)
  });
  $("#flexischeduling").click(function() {
    map.addLayer(flex)
    map.removeLayer(delivery)
    map.removeLayer(pickup)
    map.removeLayer(edap)
  });
  $("#all").click(function() {
    map.addLayer(flex)
    map.addLayer(delivery)
    map.addLayer(pickup)
    map.addLayer(edap)
  });
  //Make sure to add the slider to the map ;-)

});
my Json file:
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates":  [ -122.22,37.8147426 ]
  },
  "properties": {
  "Customer":"Stephanie Smith",
  "Sale_Order":"C19035076735",
  "fulladdress":"254 Saint James Dr Piedmont California 94611",
  "Date":"2020-12-07 00:00:00",
  "Route":"sftruck1",
  "Stop":1,
  "Scheduled_Time":"08:45 AM - 09:13 AM",
  "Type":"DELIVERY",
  "Qty_Pieces":3
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates":  [ -122.44,37.802 ]
  },
  "properties": {
  "Customer":"Vanessa Fabrizio",
  "Sale_Order":"C19033498632",
  "fulladdress":"3436 Pierce St, Unit 11 San Francisco California 94123",
  "Date":"2020-12-07 00:00:00",
  "Route":"sftruck1",
  "Stop":2,
  "Scheduled_Time":"09:44 AM - 10:12 AM",
  "Type":"DELIVERY",
  "Qty_Pieces":3
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates":  [ -122.47,37.77606235 ]
  },
  "properties": {
  "Customer":"mary walshgorski",
  "Sale_Order":"C19042525951:1207",
  "fulladdress":"659 7th Ave San Francisco California 94118",
  "Date":"2020-12-07 00:00:00",
  "Route":"sftruck1",
  "Stop":3,
  "Scheduled_Time":"10:27 AM - 10:43 AM",
  "Type":"PICKUP",
  "Qty_Pieces":-1
  }
      

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Delivery Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d19vzq90twjlae.cloudfront.net/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d19vzq90twjlae.cloudfront.net/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
      crossorigin=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder@2.3.3/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css"
      integrity="sha512-IM3Hs+feyi40yZhDH6kV8vQMg4Fh20s9OzInIIAc4nx7aMYMfo+IenRUekoYsHZqGkREUgx0VvlEsgm7nCDW9g=="
      crossorigin="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet-search.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-sidebar-v2@3.2.3/css/leaflet-sidebar.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />

    <style type="text/css">
    #map { height: 700px; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d19vzq90twjlae.cloudfront.net/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.4/mapbox.js'></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
      crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.5.0/dist/esri-leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha512-ucw7Grpc+iEQZa711gcjgMBnmd9qju1CICsRaryvX7HJklK0pGl/prxKvtHwpgm5ZHdvAil7YPxI1oWPOWK3UQ=="
      crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder@2.3.3/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.js"
      integrity="sha512-HrFUyCEtIpxZloTgEKKMq4RFYhxjJkCiF5sDxuAokklOeZ68U2NPfh4MFtyIVWlsKtVbK5GD2/JzFyAfvT5ejA=="
      crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-sidebar-v2@3.2.3/js/leaflet-sidebar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="leaflet-search.min.js"></script>
    <script src="leaflet.SliderControl.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.2/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" id="all" class="btn btn-info">All</button>
        <button type="button" id="DELIVERY" class="btn btn-success">DELIVERY</button>
        <button type="button" id="PICKUP" class="btn btn-primary">PICKUP</button>
        <button type="button" id="EXOP DELIVERY AND PICKUP" class="btn btn-warning">EXOP DELIVERY AND PICKUP</button>
        <button type="button" id="flexischeduling" class="btn btn-danger">flexischeduling</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So please help me to create a date range Filter.it should be a slicer. I have used leaflet slider .leaflet search but no use. please help me to solve this

Comment: Is any of this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977724/how-to-filter-json-data-by-date-range-in-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012366/filtering-data-in-json-for-any-date-range https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369909/how-to-update-values-in-jquery-range-slider

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.Here my thing is if we change the slider it should match with already created layers and unmatched markers should remove.any how I tried above examples which yu have given but nothing works

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle like this one? http://jsfiddle.net/ngeLm8c0/6/

Comment: Hi, that is a good example but when I move the slider all my markers changed to blue color and it seems none of the marker removed.here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/AbishekMani/shg1ve47/2/